# Corse Ecoflex 1.0 oil cap blew off

Tags: oil, opel, corsa

I was driving home on Friday and with about 3 miles to go hit a pothole pretty hard (no idea if this has anything to do with it) but also noticed it started to smoke when idle (redlight road works as well as when I finally parked home)

When I did get home other than it was super smokey I didn't notice anything negative happening to the car itself, drove fine and wasn't making any weird noises.

I looked under the bonnet and saw that the oil cap had come off and was likely on the road a few miles back - oil had gone everywhere over the engine bay as well as the roof of the car.

I've ordered a new cap for the car however does anyone know what may have caused this? the oil itself has been at a good level however hasn't been changed for maybe a year but I have been checking it every 3-6 months and seemed fine.

Any advice would be great, thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result wasn't anything too bad, replaced the cap and everything was fine - seems to have come off from the road vs anything else.